# How does one set global headers in axios?

Tags: http, http-headers, axios

Hi I'm setting default axios headers in request interceptor but these headers are not accessible in another function... in axios [axios documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#global-axios-defaults) it is mentioned that global-axios-defaults are global...below is my sample code need help

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  axios.defaults.headers.accesstoken= "some_access_token"
  axios.defaults.headers.client = "some_client"
  axios.defaults.headers.uid = "some_uid"
  return config;
},function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

On page load componentDidmount executes but axios default headers are undefined in this function

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  console.log(axios.defaults.headers) #its giving me undefined
  axios.get("http://some_url_for_get_request.json", {
    headers: {
      accesstoken: axios.defaults.headers.accesstoken,
       uid: axios.defaults.headers.uid,
       client: axios.defaults.headers.client
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I think it's because axios.default line might not executed after component mount.

Answer (score 54):

You can set the default **Custom Headers in Axios** for every XHR call like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "X-CSRFToken": "example-of-custom-header"
};
```

You can also add configurations onward like this:

```
  window.axios.defaults.headers.post['xsrfCookieName'] = 'CSRFToken';
  window.axios.defaults.headers.post['xsrfHeaderName'] = 'X-CSRFToken';
  window.axios.defaults.headers.post['responseType'] = 'json';
  window.axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

- See the global options [here (Request Config)](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config)

Also, you can create a configuration passed into an instance.

- See more: [here (Axios Create Config)](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axioscreateconfig)

Answer (score 1):

> on your MAIN.JS

```
import axios from "axios";
const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", 
});

Vue.prototype.$http = base;

  Vue.prototype.$http.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
      let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (accessToken) {
          config.headers = Object.assign({
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
          }, config.headers);
      }
      return config;
  },
  error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```